# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str

Tags: python

All my variables seem to be string data types however I keep getting the above error message

```
elif menu == 'a':
    pass
    user_1 = input("Please enter a user name: ")

    task_title = input("Please enter a title for the task to be done: ")
    task_desc = input("Please describe the task: ")
    task_due  = input("Please enter due date of the task: ")
    date_assign = str(date.today())
    with open("task.txt", "a") as fa:
        fa.write("\n" + {} + {} + {} + {} + {} + "No".format(task_title,task_desc,task_due,str(date_assign)))
```

Comment: because your `elif` starts with `pass`, it seems you have possibly not correctly indented your code.

Comment: The brackets need to go inside the quotes. `fa.write("\n{}{}{}{}{}No".format(....)`

Answer (score 2):

Your brackets need to actually be within the string itself in order to use the `str.format()` function. So your code line:

```
fa.write("\n" + {} + {} + {} + {} + {} + "No".format(task_title,task_desc,task_due,str(date_assign)))
```

should look more like this:

```
fa.write("\n{} {} {} {} No".format(task_title,task_desc,task_due,str(date_assign)))
```

Answer (score 2):

To add on to Nathan Robert's answer, consider using f-strings like so:

```
with open("task.txt", "a") as fa:
    fa.write(f"\n{task_title} {task_desc} {task_due} {date_assign} No")
```

I find them to be much cleaner then '+' string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a format string with:

```
"\n" + {} + {} + {} + {} + {} + "No"
```

You could:

```
"\n" + repr({}) + repr({}) + repr({}) + repr({}) + repr({}) + "No"
```

Which will yield:

```
"\n{}{}{}{}{}No"
```

But if you want:

```
"\n + {} + {} + {} + {} + {} + No"
```

Then you just need to eliminate two `"`s.

```
"\n + {} + {} + {} + {} + {} + No"
```

Also note that you've provided 5 sets of brackets, but only four arguments to `format`. This suggests a possible error on your part.